# In MySQL Workbench can I display UTC timestamps in my PC's time?

Tags: mysql-workbench

In MySQL Workbench can I display UTC timestamps in my PC's time?

E.g. I do not want to change the data being saved by the server, I do not wish to change the data that is inserted by the application, or the timezone it's operating in (I'm testing time zone issues in our software).

Can I display the UTC time as my local time, in order to view differences?

Can I do this without changing every query to look at the tables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To show in your current timezone, use:

```
SET time_zone = timezone;
```

For example:

```
SET time_zone = 'US/Eastern';
```

It will change the timezone only for your current session.

More information here [MySQL Server Time Zone Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html)

Comment: I can't believe I didn't know about this before - always having to decide, "are we -4, or -5, today?"